# How to add page numbers on rmarkdown beamer slide under theme: "boxes"?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, beamer

Using rmarkdown beamer, I try to add slide number at the bottom of each slide but keep failing. Is there anyway I can add slide number on each page under beamer theme called "boxes"?

```
---
title: "Big Business" 
author: |
| Mr. Bean
| Sunny College
output: 
beamer_presentation:
    theme: "boxes"
    citation_package: natbib
biblio-style: apalike 
incremental: TRUE
header-includes:
- \usepackage{makecell}
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{adjustbox}
---
# Motivation
Big business

# Motivation 2
Small business
```

Comment: Please make a [mre] we can compile without having access to your files like `header_pagenrs.tex`

Comment: @ samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: Upon your request, I entirely changed the code above so that you may reproduce them. I just want each page to have page numbers on the bottom.

Comment: you can add a footline to the boxes theme with `\addfootbox{normal text}{\hfill\insertframenumber\quad}` in your header includes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `boxes` theme has a special syntax to add things to the footline:

```
 \addfootbox{normal text}{\hfill\insertframenumber\quad}
```

(replace `<normal text>` with any other beamer colour you like)

MWE:

```
---
title: "Big Business" 
author: |
  | Mr. Bean
  | Sunny College
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: "boxes"
    citation_package: natbib
biblio-style: apalike 
incremental: TRUE
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{makecell}
  - \usepackage{booktabs}
  - \usepackage{adjustbox}
  - \addfootbox{normal text}{\hfill\insertframenumber\quad}
---

# Motivation
Big business

# Motivation 2
Small business
```

Comment: I could also add total frame number with `- \addfootbox{normal text}{\hfill\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber\quad}`.